# Rectangular Grid Tool gets hidden when I click on image, how do I stop that?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to keep the rectangular grid tool at the front as I am manipulating images in Illustrator. The problem is that as soon as I click on an image, the grid disappears. How do I keep the grid visible while changing the image?

And the image ends up going behind all the others. Even if I try to move it forward or to the front, it still does not work.

Comment: Does the grid go behind the image, or disappear altogether?

Comment: I don't understand this. The Rectangular Grid tool draws standard vector objects. It's not a guide or anything. It will stack and operate like any other object you draw in Illustrator. Could you explain your issue with a bit more detail?

Answer (score 0):

The grid appears as a whole new layer for me. Can you check your layers to make sure it's at the top? I walked through it using this: http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=599358&seqNum=6